# My bluetooth device can not find any other devices' signal - Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

My bluetooth device can not find any devices, although I turn them on. I have no ideas, can you help me?

These are some info:

**rfkill:**

```
$ sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**bluetoothctl:**

```
$ bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller AC:D1:B8:C6:3E:D2 cons [default]
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on 
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# disco
disconnect    discoverable  
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[CHG] Controller AC:D1:B8:C6:3E:D2 DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
[CHG] Controller AC:D1:B8:C6:3E:D2 Discoverable: no
[CHG] Controller AC:D1:B8:C6:3E:D2 Discovering: no
[CHG] Controller AC:D1:B8:C6:3E:D2 Discoverable: yes
Agent unregistered
[DEL] Controller AC:D1:B8:C6:3E:D2 cons [default]
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
```

service:

```
~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-08-13 21:03:04 +07; 1min 23s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 6026 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─6026 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Aug 13 21:03:04 cons systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Aug 13 21:03:04 cons bluetoothd[6026]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
Aug 13 21:03:04 cons systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Aug 13 21:03:04 cons bluetoothd[6026]: Starting SDP server
Aug 13 21:03:04 cons bluetoothd[6026]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initi
Aug 13 21:03:04 cons bluetoothd[6026]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.38 path=/M
Aug 13 21:03:04 cons bluetoothd[6026]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.38 path=/M
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in terminal

```
bluetoothctl
```

Then

```
power on
```

Then

```
scan on
```

should all be done back to back, if that don't work, try installing *Blueman GUI* program with this command

```
sudo apt-get install blueman -y
```

Comment: It doesnt work too, I can not find any devices. Besides, tab `Devices` is invisible (disable)